# LESS Compiler PHP with Wordpress 4.0.1 and Bootstrap 3

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to add a php-compiler in my new Wordpress Theme. Therefore I followed this Tutorial: http://www.tailored4wp.com/how-to-use-less-auto-compiler-in-your-next-wordpress-project-quick-tip-361/

**My functions.php**

```
/**
* LESS Compiler.
*/
function autoCompileLess() {

    // include lessc.inc
    require_once( get_template_directory().'/less/lessc.inc.php' );

    // input and output location
    $inputFile = get_template_directory().'/less/bootstrap.less';
    $outputFile = get_template_directory().'/css/bootstrap_less.css';

    // load the cache
    $cacheFile = $inputFile.".cache";

    if (file_exists($cacheFile)) {
        $cache = unserialize(file_get_contents($cacheFile));
    } else {
        $cache = $inputFile;
    }

    $less = new lessc;
    // create a new cache object, and compile
    $newCache = $less->cachedCompile($cache);

    // output a LESS file, and cache file only if it has been modified since last compile
    if (!is_array($cache) || $newCache["updated"] > $cache["updated"]) {
        file_put_contents($cacheFile, serialize($newCache));
        file_put_contents($outputFile, $newCache['compiled']);
    }
}
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap_less.css' ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts' );
```

If I change some less files, there won’t be any file in output-directory. (I set the right permissions)

And if I add

```
if(is_user_logged_in()) {
add_action(‘init’, ‘autoCompileLess’);
}
```

…/wp-admin will show a blank page with no code in it. What’s wrong?

********EDIT*************

I copied the Theme to XAMPP Installation and got these Errors:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'parse error:
>   failed at `&:extend(.clearfix all);`
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/themes/templateName/less/mixins/grid.less
>   on line 11' in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\templateName\less\lessc.inc.php:3460
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\templateName\less\lessc.inc.php(2273):
>   lessc_parser->throwError() #1
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\templateName\less\lessc.inc.php(121):
>   lessc_parser->parse('// Grid system?...') #2
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\templateName\less\lessc.inc.php(753):
>   lessc->tryImport(Array, Object(stdClass), Object(stdClass)) #3
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\templateName\less\lessc.inc.php(162):
>   lessc->compileProp(Array, Object(stdClass), Object(stdClass)) #4
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\templateName\less\lessc.inc.php(147):
>   lessc->compileImportedProps(Array, Object(stdClass), Object(stdClass),
>   Object(lessc_parser), 'D:\xampp\htdocs...') #5
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\w in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\templateName\less\lessc.inc.php
>   on line 3460

Comment: Try to debug your code first http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG to find out why you get an error in the first place.

Comment: Hey, the WB_DEBUG is turned on:
`/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY' true)`

But I can't see anything... it's also an empty page... 
I think the server does not provide php errors and debugging etc.

Comment: I copied the Theme to XAMPP Wordpress Installation and got many Errors. I edited the Question above.

Comment: see: https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/issues/580

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, based on *Bass Jobsons* comments, thanks to Bass Jobson:

**Leafo/lessphp** is not compatible to Bootstrap 3.1.1 and it seems not to be actively developed anymore. So I changed to **oyejorge/lessphp**.

https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php/

> Transitioning from Leafo/lessphp
>
> Projects looking for an easy transition from leafo/lessphp can use the
>   lessc.inc.php adapter. To use, Download the less.php source code and
>   unzip the files into your project so that the new 'lessc.inc.php'
>   replaces the existing 'lessc.inc.php'.
>
> Note, the 'setPreserveComments' will no longer have any effect on the
>   compiled less.